# "Whose ever" instead of "Who's ever"

Tags: grammaticality, difference, word-difference

I sometimes hear non-natives say "**Whose ever**" instead of "**Who's ever**". Then maybe they confuse it with "**Whoever's**"?

Where could this come from and is it any way correct?

- *You can take whose ever/who's ever/whoever's seat you want.*

Comment: How can you tell which they are saying? They sound like homophones to me.

Comment: @J.R. **hear say** isn't exactly what it means. I meant I stumble upon such confusion.

Comment: You should say "write" if you read it; "say" if you hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of the three options are correct:

- You can take whose ever seat you want. (*More formal*)
- You can take whoever's seat you want. (*More colloquial*)

"Who's ever" is incorrect (unless it stands for "who is ever" or "who has ever", which it can't in this sentence).

The possessive form of "who" is always "whose", although "who's" is a commonly seen misspelling.

(Fowler's *Modern English Usage*, 1965, has: **whoever**. Forms. Subjective: *whoever*, *whosoever* (emphatic), *who-e'er* (poetic), *whoso* (archaic), *whosoe'er* (poetic). Objective: *whomever* (rare), *whoever* (colloq.), *whomsoever* (literary), *whomsoe'er* (poetic), *whomso* (archaic). Possessive: *whose ever*, *whoever's* (colloq.), *whosesoever* (archaic).)

Note: I was unaware until I read Rompey's answer that there exists an alternative one-word spelling ("whosever"); this isn't mentioned in the 1965 edition of Fowler's but is included in the 1996 edition.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever reliable dictionary you look up "whosever" in, you'll find out that it is a single word meaning "belonging to whichever person/of whomever".

For example:

[The choice, whosever it was, is interesting.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whosever)

So, no apostrophe is needed in

> You can take whosever seat you want.

Comment: Exactly what Victor said. It's a single word, no spaces or apostrophes. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/whosever